# How can I find projection of $x^3$ in $L^2[-1.1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In $L^2[-1,1]$ with the usual $L^2$ integral norm, define
$$
p_0 = 1, \quad p_1(x) =x, \quad  p_2(x) = x^2, \quad p_3(x)=x^3. 
$$
Let $M$ be the subspace generated by $p_0,p_1,p_2$. Then how can I find projection of $p_3$ on $M$, denoted $P_M(x^3)$? Can I do this by Gram-Shmidt Process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Construct from the basis $(p_i)_{0\le i\le 2}$ using the Shmidt process an orthonormal basis $(q_i)_{0\le i\le 2}$ then

$$P_M(x^3)=\sum_{i=0}^2\langle x^3,q_i\rangle q_i$$

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Gram-Schmidt or with a little hat-trick, that is to exploit the fact that [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) give a complete base of $L^2([-1,1])$ with the standard inner product. Since:

$$ P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[(x^2-1)^n\right] $$
by [Rodrigues' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula), we have:
$$ P_0(x)=1,\qquad P_1(x)=x,\qquad P_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1),\qquad P_3(x)=\frac{1}{2}(5x^3-3x) $$
and:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx = \frac{2\delta_{n,m}}{2n+1}.$$
Since $x^3 = \frac{2}{5} P_3(x) + \frac{3}{5} P_1(x)$, the projection of $x^3$ on $\langle 1,x,x^2\rangle$ is simply given by:
$$\frac{3}{5}P_1(x) = \color{red}{\frac{3}{5}x}.$$